# jQuery loop giving all <select> options instead of option:selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a table that I need to loop through and get the values from, then store them in an array. Right now this loop is giving me all the values, however when it encounters an `HTML` < select> element it returns the selected option *then* it gives me **all** of the select options. I only want the selected option, **not** the entire list.

This is much easier to explain by showing you. So here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WNSBk/6/) and here is the `jQuery` code

```
var saveEdits = [];
$('#save').click(function () {
    $('.projects_editable_tbody tr').each(function () {
        $('.projects_editable_content_td, option:selected', this).each(function () {
            var $input = $("input", this);
            if ($input.length) {
                saveEdits.push($input.val());
            } else saveEdits.push($(this).text());
        });
    });
    $.each(saveEdits, function (index, value) {        
        console.log(index + ': ' + value);
    });
});
```

As you can see from the fiddle the array is populating *almost* exactly like I want it to. Any help is appreciated. If you need more info/code just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for making a separate question out of this :) - was the right thing to do

Comment: @IanClark ya, I really don't think it went 'out of scope' necessarily but it was still two separate questions. Thank you for the help on the other one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's giving you the text from the td that contains the select, because you've specified .projects_editable_content_td. You need to exclude the .projects_editable_content_td that contain a select. See the code I posted to your question from yesterday.

Comment: so silly, I was just missing the `:not(:has(select))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but I tinkered with your code to push the current selected value of each select, instead the select itself. I also edited the content of the select boxes to use "selected" prop.

```
    $('.projects_editable_content_td', this).each(function () {
            if(jQuery(this).children().val()) {
                  saveEdits.push($(this).children().val());
            } else {
                 saveEdits.push(jQuery.trim($(this).text()) );
            }
    });
```

You can see in this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/WNSBk/29/

The first row is edited and it returns a correct array. The second one was left as it was and still has the problem.

In your scenario it would probably be better if you enclosed each line in  tags and harvest the data using the serialize() method of the form. For this you would need to make every field an input. For example, you could put a hidden field next to text elements.

Comment: interesting. I like it. +1. Not exactly what I was looking for, but I like the angle you took on this.